# React - render certain div based on react-select selectedOption

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [`react-select`](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) to render two types of "job" options. From the dropdown the user is able to select either of the options. Based on the option selected they should render different divs that contain more input values. The input values are dependent on the `selectedOption`. I have two class components with render methods that should display the different inputs corresponding to the `jobType`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedOption: null
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.set({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log([e.target.value]);
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log("Option selected: ", selectedOption);
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Parameters</legend>
          <label htmlFor="jobType" style={{ display: "block" }}>
            jobType:
          </label>
          <div>
            <Select
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Select a jobType..."
              isSearchable={options}
            />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>
          {selectedOption === "Batch" ? (
            <BatchParams />
          ) : selectedOption === "Streaming" ? (
            <StreamingParams />
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So let's say when the `Streaming` option is selected from the dropdown the following class component should be rendered:

```
class StreamingParams extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          maxHits: 1
        };
        this.handleMaxHitsChange = this.handleMaxHitsChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleMaxHitsChange = e => {
        this.set({ [e.target.name]: e.target.valu });
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <label>maxHits:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="maxHits"
              onChange={this.handleMaxHitsChange}
              placeholder="1"
              min="1"
              step="1"
              required
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

I can't quite get the additional input boxes to render, not sure if I'm taking the correct approach here. I have included a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/88435w189l) with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like the value that is getting set in `this.state.selectedOption` is an object with a `value` and a `label` field.

[image]

So you need to key off of those. Instead of doing this

```
          {selectedOption === "Batch" ? (
            <BatchParams />
          ) : selectedOption === "Streaming" ? (
            <StreamingParams />
          ) : null}
```

Do this

```
          {selectedOption && selectedOption.value === "batch" ? (
            <BatchParams />
          ) : selectedOption && selectedOption.value === "streaming" ? (
            <StreamingParams />
```

You should opt for `value` instead of `label` in case of localization or translations.

Fork
https://codesandbox.io/s/ll5p30nx5q

Comment: You all very adequately answered the question with ample explanation, than you.
Also +1 for mentioning use of `value` over `label`

Comment: Hey that was my idea! No worries, better to learn from others than advocating your code.

Comment: @Siavas I very much appreciate your time and effort looking into my issue. After edits the answers were of no discernible difference. If I could mark both as solutions I certainly would!

Answer (score 2):

Only the ternary operator has to be changed: find an updated codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o44r6l3jz9).

In the ternary operators you will have to check `this.state.selectedOption.value` as that is where your option value is stored.

```
{!this.state.selectedOption ? 
    null : 
    this.state.selectedOption.value === "batch" ? (
        <BatchParams />
    ) : (
        <StreamingParams />
    )
}
```

Also you will have to first check for null as that is the initial value you get for `this.state.selectedOption` when no element in the select has been set.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that you have to take the value in the selectedOptions and assign that value to the selectedOption in the event handler setState. You were trying to assign an object and therefore the issue. Have made the changes in the sandbox also. Hope it helps.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

import "./styles.css";

const options = [
  { value: "batch", label: "Batch" },
  { value: "streaming", label: "Streaming" }
];

class BatchParams extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      batchNumber: 1
    };
    this.handleBatchNumChange = this.handleBatchNumChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleBatchNumChange = e => {
    this.set({ [e.target.name]: e.target.valu });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>batchNumberSize:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="batchNumberSize"
          onChange={this.handleBatchNumChange}
          placeholder="1"
          min="1"
          step="1"
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class StreamingParams extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      maxHits: 1
    };
    this.handleMaxHitsChange = this.handleMaxHitsChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleMaxHitsChange = e => {
    this.set({ [e.target.name]: e.target.valu });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>maxHits:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="maxHits"
          onChange={this.handleMaxHitsChange}
          placeholder="1"
          min="1"
          step="1"
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedOption: null
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.set({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log([e.target.value]);
  };

  handleChange =( {value}) => {
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ selectedOption: value });
    
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Parameters</legend>
          <label htmlFor="querySchemaName" style={{ display: "block" }}>
            jobType:
          </label>
          <div>
            <Select
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
              placeholder="Select a jobType..."
              isSearchable={options}
            />
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div>

          {selectedOption === "batch" && <BatchParams /> }
          {selectedOption === "streaming" && <StreamingParams />}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```